# Which partitions $P$ of $n$ give the row and column sums of some $|P| \times |P|$ $(0,1)$-matrix?

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, integer-partitions

*Question*: Which partitions $P$ of $n$ give the row and column sums of some $|P| \times |P|$ $(0,1)$-matrix?

Someone comes along and gives us the partition $P=\{2,2,3,3,4\}$ of $14$.  How can we determine if there's a $5 \times 5$ matrix whose rows and column sums both give rise to that partition?

In the example, it's realized by this matrix:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 
1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \end{bmatrix}$$
but I cheated: I generated the example partition from the matrix.

---

Observations:

- The obvious necessary condition is that $\max P \leq |P|$.
- This is equivalent to asking when is $P$ the out-degree sequence of a directed graph where any vertex may have one loop.  (So the [Erdős–Gallai theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93Gallai_theorem) or [Havel–Hakimi algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Havel%E2%80%93Hakimi_algorithm) could be applied in some cases, replacing each undirected edge with a bidirected edge; in fact, they would work in my above example.)
- If we just brute force started filling in $1$'s, we can get stuck.  Here I proceed row-by-row, placing a $1$ wherever possible:
  $$
  \begin{array}{c|ccccc}
    & 4 & 3 & 3 & 2 & 2 \\
  \hline
  4 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
  3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  3 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  2 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  2 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & ??? \\
  \end{array}
  $$

---

Motivation:

This is a first step in an attempt at answering my Mathoverflow question: [What is the minimum number of filled cells in a partial Latin rectangle with autotopism group $\cong C_2$ and autoparatopism group $\cong S_3$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/212332/48278).  An answer to this question might help reduce the search space.

Comment: This is answered by the [Gale-Ryser Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gale%E2%80%93Ryser_theorem).

Comment: See, e.g., Manfred Krause, A simple proof of the Gale-Ryser theorem, Amer. Math. Monthly 103 (1996), 335-337.

Comment: Great!  Thanks; that certainly answers my question.  Want to make it an answer?  (I wonder if it simplifies in the symmetric case I'm considering.)

Comment: Huh.  I searched on here, but it seems I didn't succeed.  (In any case, at least I know the answer to my question now.)